# View not updating after change in Google API callback

Tags: angular, typescript, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to implement a service that will use the Google API to log the user in and authorize the Sheets API. A simplified version of that service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

declare var gapi;

@Injectable()
export class MyService{
    isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    clientId: string = "*******.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    scopes: string[] = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"];


    constructor(){
        gapi.load('client', () => {
            console.log("Client Loaded");
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: this.clientId,
                scope: this.scopes.join(' '),
                immediate: true
            }, (authResponse) => {
                if(authResponse && !authResponse.error){
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    console.log("User logged in, " + this.isLoggedIn);
                }
                else{
                    this.isLoggedIn = false;
                    console.log("User not logged in");
                    console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I'm injecting that service to my AppComponent as a `private myService: MyService`. In my `app.component.html` I have a simple button that should be visible if the user has not authorized the API:

`<button *ngIf="!myService.isLoggedIn">Authorize</button>`

So what I want is:
- The service calls `gapi.auth.authorize` 
- If the user has authorized the API, then `isLoggedIn` should be set to `true` and the button should vanish
- If immediate authorization fails, the button should be visible so the user can trigger the authorization manually.

The issue I'm facing is that when immediate authorization succeeds and "User logged in, true" is printed in the console window, the button stays visible. The `*ngIf` bind does not work. The change in `isLoggedIn` is not reflected. I found a similar post [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491871/angular2-view-not-updating-after-variable-changes-in-settimeout) but I had already suspected that it may have to do with the callbacks so I had already tried changing the value from a `setTimeout` within a `setTimeout` within another `setTimeout` and the view successfully updates.

I finally found a solution by injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` as `private detector` and calling `detector.detectChanges()` after setting a value for `isLoggedIn`.

So I'm not asking for a solution, what I'm asking is if someone knows why this weird behavior happens and why do I have to use the change detector for an operation that, to me at least, seems like something that should be handled by Angular itself. Or am I missing something and this behavior is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gapi` is not covered by Zone.js. You need to invoke change detection explicitly:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){
    gapi.load('client', () => {
        console.log("Client Loaded");
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: this.clientId,
            scope: this.scopes.join(' '),
            immediate: true
        }, (authResponse) => {
            if(authResponse && !authResponse.error){
                this.isLoggedIn = true;
                console.log("User logged in, " + this.isLoggedIn);
            }
            else{
                this.isLoggedIn = false;
                console.log("User not logged in");
                console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
            }
            cdRef.detectChanges(); // <<<< added
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did and it worked. So this all has to do with how Zone works?

Comment: I guess it's because you initialize gapi outside Angular, therefore NgZone is not aware of its async API calls. It's also possible if you initialize it inside Angular that it somehow processes events without zone noticing. NgZone doesn't cover 100% of all possibilities.