# Angular 5 View Not Updating After Timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I'm setting a timeout to hide an element after a while in Angular 5:

```
this.showElement = true;
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('hide');
  this.showElement = false;
}, 2000);
```

However, this doesn't update the view. The `console.log` gives me an output, so the timeout definitely works.

I have found that in Angularjs you needed to call `$apply` in order to start a digest, so I'm guessing I just need to find the Angular 5 equivalent way of doing that.

Comment: you don't need change detection or even a timeout for that, just two-way bind this.showElement to a *NgIf on the element itself and it'll remove and show it on demand. beware of the timeout usage it can be resource consuming and will kill your application if you'll ever want to make it universal.

Comment: One thing to add is that in Angular 1.x, there is a $timeout service that you would use. In Angular 2+, there is no $timeout service. It is preferred/recommended to use arrow function where you want to keep the lexical scope of the component/service context.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think the `setTimeout` callback lose a scope to the "showElement" variable.

```
this.showElement = true; // this - is in component object context
setTimeout(function () {
   console.log('hide');
   this.showElement = false; // here... this has different context
}, 2000);
```

You should use arrow function:

```
this.showElement = true;
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('hide');
  this.showElement = false;
}, 2000);
```

Or use `bind`:

```
this.showElement = true;
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('hide');
  this.showElement = false;
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

to pass proper context to the `setTimeout` callback function.

Answer (score 13):

In your constructor, add a change detector:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

And then in your *setTimeout*:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('hide');
  this.showElement = false;
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: any explanation?

Answer (score 7):

**Updated: Corrected answer.**

As the others has correctly answered, the reason why the changes are not being reflected is because of the incorrect reference to the `this` reference.

Note that when using the `function() { ... }` notation, the reference to `this` is the context of the function itself. So

```
myFunction() {
    this.showElement = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.showElement); // Will result in undefined;
      this.showElement = false; // Here, this, reference to context of the function wrapper
    }, 2000);
}
```

Changing the above to ES6 arrow notation, changes the context of the `this` reference to the parent context. So

```
myFunction() {
    this.showElement = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.showElement); // Will result in true;
      this.showElement = false; // Here, value is updated
    }, 2000);
}
```

Read more about the `lexical this` [here](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis).

Comment: Had the same problem in Ionic 4, this was the correct solution.

Comment:  your answer is the correct one it is not about the **scope** and **this** is not the **scope**. 

Answer (score 3):

when you use function style "this" reference is not working 
do it like following and your example will work correctly

```
this.showElement = true;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hide');
    this.showElement = false;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem in my Angular 7 app. I had to change the source of title and icon in button:

```
<button class="btn btn--outline-red text-uppercase font-weight-normal product-action-btn mt-3"
              (click)="addToCart()">
              {{addToCartProps.title}}
              <img style="width:15px; height:15px;" [src]="addToCartProps.src">
            </button>
```

.......

```
  addToCartProps = { title: 'Add to Cart', src: '' }

  addToCart() {

    this.addToCartProps.title = 'Adding';
    this.addToCartProps.src = 'assets/images/preloader-white.svg';

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.addToCartProps.title = 'Added';
      this.addToCartProps.src = 'assets/images/checked-icon-white.svg';
      this.cd.markForCheck();
      console.log('timeout 1 ', this.addToCartProps);
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.addToCartProps.title = 'Add to cart';
      this.addToCartProps.src = '';
      this.cd.markForCheck();
      console.log('timeout 2 ', this.addToCartProps);
    }, 1500);

  }
```

Adding **this.cd.markForCheck()** in timeout function solved the problem in my case.

Earlier this was also commented by @artemisian in [Angular2, view not updating after variable changes in settimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491871/angular2-view-not-updating-after-variable-changes-in-settimeout/34492260)

Answer (score 0):

It is updating the value, but problem is of `this`. you can set value of this by bind or arrow function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('hide');
  this.showElement = false;
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

Or we can use arrow function because its this value is setup containing function.

```
this.showElement = true;
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('hide');
  this.showElement = false;
}, 2000);
```