# MapQuest and Leaflet plugin - map not showed after refresh

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ionic3, angular5, mapquest

I'm working with Ionic 3 and Angular 5 and I want to display a map on my app. I created a map component but **I get troubles to display the map after a page refresh**.

## MapComponent

### map.html

```
<div id="map" style="height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>
```

### map.ts

Basically, I create a new raw map element to avoid intializing the map on the same HTML element, which causes a Leaflet error ("map container is already initialized")

```
ngOnInit() {
    var map: any = null;
    var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
    mapElement.parentElement.innerHTML = '<div id="map" style="height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>';
    console.log("new map element created");
    var initMap = function () {
        console.log("init map..");
        L.mapquest.key = 'XXXXXX';
        map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
          center: [37.7749, -122.4194],
          layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
          zoom: 15
        });
    }
    initMap();
}
```

## Result

The map is correctly displayed the first time. But when I go back a second time on the page where the map is displayed, I don't get any error but I just get a blank div element, as if Leaflet could not init the map. 
Also, in the console I see that the element is created before the map is initialized, so it should work.

Do you have any inputs to help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to navigate around your application?

Comment: Ionic NavController's push method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ionViewDidEnter()

```
ionViewDidEnter() { 
var map: any = null;
var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
mapElement.parentElement.innerHTML = '<div id="map" style="height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>';
console.log("new map element created");
var initMap = function () {
    console.log("init map..");
    L.mapquest.key = 'XXXXXX';
    map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
      center: [37.7749, -122.4194],
      layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
      zoom: 15
    });
}
initMap();
}
```

ionViewDidEnter() runs whenever you enter the page, regardless if it was cached or not.

Comment: Edited my answer, try it out

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am working on a single component that is included to a page. This event is not fired when the map component is displayed.

Comment: So, the map does not display at all when using ionViewDidEnter()?

Comment: yeah, because the function is never fired. 

In my code, ngOnInit is fired because my class implements OnInit interface.

Comment: Try putting `setTimeout()` function in your ngOnInit function before loading the map. Check the answer on this question for reference [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900860/angular-5-view-not-updating-after-timeout)

Comment: I'm not conviced about this, it seems to be an unproper way to achieve the requirements. I saw other ways to wait for an external library to be loaded, like on this post https://dev.to/timber/wait-for-a-script-to-load-in-javascript-579k

Comment: Thanks anyway for your feedback !